# Header not showing on iPhones

Tags: css, media

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmK9B.jpg)Sorry, another newb. requiring help, please??

I have created a site (first site for 15 years) and there are a couple of things i'd like to know but the first and most important one is, why does my site header not show on iPhones?
[Android showing header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfaiq.jpg)
[iPhone without header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39rOV.jpg)

I have added the viewport meta tag   but it didn't change anything.

Another thing l have read on here is adding @media but it didn't say where to add it so l tried a few places without success.

Can someone help me please?

Test page code

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="left-sidebar">

    <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header">
            <div class="container">
                    
                <!-- Logo -->
                    <div id="logo">
                        <h2><a href="#">Dress Up Leeds Ltd</a></h2>
                    </div>
                
                <!-- Nav -->
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                             <li><a href="index.html" class="button" title="Home Button" target="_self">home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="store.html" class="button" title="Dress Up Store Button" target="_self">store</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="contact.html" class="button" title="Contact Us Button" target="_self">contact us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html" class="button" title="About Dress Up Button" target="_self">about</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

            </div>
        </div>
```

style.css for header

```
header
    {
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        line-height: 1.7em;
    }
    
        header h2
        {
            font-size: 2.5em;
        }

        header .byline
        {
            display: block;
            margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
            padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1.4em;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }
```

and

```
#header
    {
        position: relative;
        background: #FFF;
    }

        #header .container
        {
            position: relative;
            padding: 4em 0em;
        }
```

style-mobile.css for header

header
{
}

```
    header h2
    {
        font-size: 1.6em;
    }

    header .byline
    {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
```

and

```
#header
    {
        display: none;
    }

    #logo
    {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #nav
    {
        display: none;
    }
```

style-mobile css the whole file

```
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Basic                                                                         */
/*********************************************************************************/

    body,input,textarea,select
    {
        line-height: 1.75em;
        font-size: 11pt;
        letter-spacing: 0;
    }

    body
    {
        padding-top: 44px;
    }

    h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
    {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    section,
    article
    {
        clear: both;
        margin: 2em 0 2em 0 !important;
    }

    section > :first-child,
    article > :first-child
    {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }

    section:first-child,
    article:first-child
    {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }

    .container
    {
        padding: 0em 1em;
    }
    
    .button
    {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    header
    {
    }
    
        header h2
        {
            font-size: 1.6em;
        }

        header .byline
        {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
    
/*********************************************************************************/
/* UI                                                                            */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #titleBar
    {
        background: #202020 url(images/img01.jpg) repeat;
    }

        #titleBar .title
        {
            display: block;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 44px;
        }

        #titleBar .toggle
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 80px;
            height: 60px;
        }

            #titleBar .toggle:after
            {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                width: 20px;
                height: 12px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 10px;
                top: 15px;
                background: url('images/toggle.svg') 0px 0px no-repeat;
                opacity: 0.5;
            }

            #titleBar .toggle:active:after
            {
                opacity: 0.75;
            }

    #navPanel
    {
        background: #202020 url(images/img01.jpg) repeat;
        box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

        #navPanel .link
        {
            display: block;
            color: #888;
            text-decoration: none;
            height: 44px;
            line-height: 44px;
            border-top: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
        }
        
            #navPanel .link:first-child
            {
                border-top: 0;
            }
            
            #navPanel .link.depth-0
            {
                color: #fff;
            }

            #navPanel .indent-1 { display: inline-block; width: 1em; }
            #navPanel .indent-2 { display: inline-block; width: 2em; }
            #navPanel .indent-3 { display: inline-block; width: 3em; }
            #navPanel .indent-4 { display: inline-block; width: 4em; }
            #navPanel .indent-5 { display: inline-block; width: 5em; }
            #navPanel .depth-0 { color: #fff; }
            
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Header                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #header
    {
        display: block;
    }

    #logo
    {
        display: block;
    }
    
    #nav
    {
        display: block;
    }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Banner                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #banner
    {
        padding: 6em 0em;
    }


/*********************************************************************************/
/* Main                                                                          */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #page
    {
        padding: 2em 0em 2em 0em;
    }

    #main
    {
        margin-top: 3em;
        padding-top: 0em;
        border-top: none;
    }

    
    .homepage #main
    {
        margin-top: 3em;
        padding-top: 3em;
    }
    
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Footer                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/
    
    #footer
    {
        padding: 0em 0em 2em 0em;
    }
    
/*********************************************************************************/
/* Featured                                                                      */
/*********************************************************************************/
    
    #featured
    {
        position: relative;
        padding: 4em 0em 2em 0em;
    }
    
    #featured .divider
    {
        padding: 2em 0em 0em 0em;
    }
    
    #featured .left
    {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Share your code or if you can't share, create a small page that replicates your page and share that code here. It is hard to help without looking at your implementation.

Comment: We need to see the html and css.

Comment: Thanks for the initial input @Kavindra, do i need to add anything more?

Comment: Thanks for the initial input @kloddant, do i need to add anything more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#header {
    display: block;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
}

#nav {
    display: block;
}
```

display: none hides elements, so your css is hiding your header.  The viewport tag makes no difference in whether or not the header is hidden.  I am missing context here, but your css looks like it is very intentionally hiding your header, so I am guessing it was written by someone else?  If so, that person may have written it with the intent of applying these css rules for one screen size and applying a different set of rules for another screen size, but perhaps they left the task unfinished, or we are only seeing a small part of the css here.  If that is the case, then you should look into using media queries to apply different sets of rules for different screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks @kloddant, i have added an image of how it looks with 'block'. It looks like a mini desktop

Comment: the screen size changes are fine and changes perfectly at 1200px and fine on android but not on iPhone

Comment: Sorry, l should have said it looks like a mini desktop but a mangled mini desktop.

Comment: You can now see the whole style-mobile css file

Comment: Thank you @kloddant, now it is showing i can make it vertical etc.